# PHP file_get_contents with mixed media (html/images)

Tags: php, html, email, file-get-contents

I am working on a project that contains html email templates. The content is essentially be seen in the browser if you view it directly and all is working fine. It contains mostly text with a logo.

In my PHP, I am trying to get the contents of this HTML template and send it as my HTML email.

Everything is coming through except for the images:

```
<?php 

// vars
$subject = 'Test Email Subject';
$body = file_get_contents("communication.php");

// Email
$objEmail = new SendMail;
$objEmail
   -> setFrom('noreply@domain.com')
   -> setTo('user@domain.com')
   -> setSubject($subject)
   -> sendHTMLEmail($body);

?>
```

The HTML it self is just a basic div with an `img` tag containing the full path to the image.

I assume that `file_get_contents` is only getting the code and wouldn't be downloading anything.

Any reason a direct link to an image wouldn't work or do they need to be encoded into the email somehow?

Comment: `file_get_contents` reads the file as a text file. meaning it would read the source of the php file, not parse it's content and output.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn - Is there a PHP function that would handle this or does the image need to be encoded differently?

Comment: there are a few ways you could get it to work. I would be wary depending on the contents of the file. As a "quick fix", you could start output buffering, include the file, and then capture the output to your body variable. Look at [ob_start](http://php.net/ob_start) and [ob_get_clean](http://php.net/ob_get_clean).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose communication.php is your template and you use PHP because you have some variables inside.

Basically you shouldn't do a file_get_contents on a .php file because the content will be a source code of the file.

You have 3 solutions

1 / The 1st is to built a template.html (no matter what the extension is) with custom variables. You can decide how you want your variables to be written ##firstname## {{lastname}} ...

While you have you the body you apply some replacements

```
$tpl = file_get_contents("template.html");
$search = array('##lastname##');
$replace = array($lastname);
$body = str_replace($search, $replace, $tpl);
```

2/ The 2nd is the best. According to the mailer you can have plugin. You can look swiftmailer with its decorator plugin
http://swiftmailer.org/docs/plugins.html#decorator-plugin

3/ Use a template engine like twig and catch the output in a buffer with ob_start, ob_flush

Comment: This seems like it could help. I will have to figure out a way to create an array with all the replacements so I can do it all in one go